# Remove a single text html element without class or id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a theme which can't be changed (because of automatic update reasons). The following bit of html exists in the theme:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a href="#">Profile</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I need to hide the "Profile" link and the pipe character, without modifying the themes html. (purely visual)

The profile link is an easy one:

```
.dropdown-profile a:first-of-type{
display: none;
}
```

But how can i remove the pipe (|) character with css or javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding following styles

```
.dropdown-menu {
    font-size : 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a:last-of-type{
    font-size: initial; // or some other value
}
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/0p5L83zm/

Comment: Cheers for the idea, i gave it a shot and initial seems to work fine. Except in my case when i replace 'initial' with a number, for example 15px, the element is hidden. I need to do this because, initial seems to reset the original font size. I highly suspect this only happens in my special case, cause your jsfiddle works fine. I also tried with !important, but no luck there. [edit] Found the problem, you can't seem to specify font size with "em" anymore, when i specify font size with "px" it works fine!

Comment: @TinusSky - As you said changing value to 15px works fine in fiddle. Can you share your code or a place where it is not working so that I can debug further.

Comment: try using  font-size: 2em; in your jsfiddle, the Logout text disappears. I was using 2em in my case, but tested with 15px in your jsfiddle, didn't know their could be a difference. Using px works without problems. I suspect em uses the font size of parent: 2 * 0 font size = 0, that makes a sense.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. em is relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to manipulate the element's innerHTML property.
JavaScript:

```
foo = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu');
foo = foo.item(0);
foo.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>Profile</a> <a href='#'>Logout</a>";
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7d81g4g/

Comment: this approach will indeed also work! In addition i would use a regular expression and reuse the element content. Cheers for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery go for

```
$(".dropdown-menu").empty();
```

If you want pure javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu').innerHtml = "";
```